# How to code cover anonymous functions in Angular using Karma Jasmine?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

```
noDefaultColType(columnDatatype: string, column: string, direction: 1 | -1,defaultColumn: string ){
let s;
if (columnDatatype === 'Date') {
  s = firstBy(**function** (
    v1: Record<string, string>,
    v2: Record<string, string>
  ) {
    ***return new Date(v1[column]) > new Date(v2[column])***
      ? -1
      : new Date(v1[column]) < new Date(v2[column])
      ? 1
      : 0;
  },
  direction).thenBy(
    (**a**: Record<string, string>, b: Record<string, string>) =>
      **this.sortColumnHelper(a, b, defaultColumn),**
    1
  );
} 
return s;
```

}

Above is a function I have. I have written as much as I could but I am unable to code cover the potions marked in bold. Can someone help?